# Compare variable values, return variable name and the corresponding variable value of largest value using max()

Tags: python

```
a = 123
b = 124
c = 345
d = 444
larger_value = max([a,b,c,d])
```

The purpose of the code:

find out the larger variable name and variable values of more than three variables, but I dont know how to return the coresponding variable name.

Comment: You can't really do that in this way. Best you could do is create a dictionary and get the key with the highest value.

Comment: Variable names are not data. If the name is important, it should be a key in a `dict`.

Comment: Why do you _need_ to return the variable name?  This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: See [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: it's not recommended you do the following, but it is possible.

Without using a dictionary, you can try this:

```py
a = 123
b = 124
c = 345
d = 444
larger_value = max(['a','b','c','d'], key=lambda x: globals()[x])

print(larger_value)
```

Output:

```py
d
```

Comment: This is not a good substitute for an explicit `dict`, though.

Comment: Not at all, more so to illustrate the point that doing it like this is not a good idea.

Comment: That's not what the average reader is going to take away from this answer. They're going to see that someone posted it as an answer, and assume that it's an acceptable way to write code.

Comment: Good call. I'll add a disclaimer.